# Undefined error when trying to access an element in JSON array from fetch response

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to access an element from an API that returns an array data from a submit function. I can access the entire object but when trying to access a specific element like `specCode` in the object I get an undefined error. I'm not sure why since that element exists in the array.

```
function App() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
  const [specList, setSpecList] = useState([]);

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://fishbase.ropensci.org/comnames?Comname=" + searchText)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setSpecList(data);
      });


    // Works
    console.log(specList[0])

    //Undefined
    console.log(specList[0].SpecCode)
  };

  return ( 

 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            class="form-control mr-1"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Large input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search for Fish by Name"
            value={searchText}
            onChange={event => setSearchText(event.target.value)}
          />
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            enter
          </button>
        </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: The dupe question and the first answer it's enough for understanding the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why since that element exists in the array.

It **doesn't** … yet.

> ```
> const [specList, setSpecList] = useState([]);
> ```

`specList` is an **empty** array.

> ```
> // Works
> console.log(specList[0])
> ```

This logs `undefined`. This is fine.

> ```
> //Undefined
> console.log(specList[0].SpecCode)
> ```

You are trying to read the `SpecCode` property of `undefined`. This is **not** fine and throws an exception.

Check that `specList[0]` has a value before you try to do anything with it.

---

See also:

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).
- [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays).